# Lambda with EFS performance issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I'm using lambda with EFS, and seeing very high latencies, making the whole solution unusable.

Writing small files (1KB) start from 20ms and add up significantly if I write in 100 concurrent threads.

When I batch to larger files I'm still getting +50ms latencies.

Reading the docs, (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html), they promise sub millisecond latencies.

Am I doing something wrong?

The code I'm using to write is a simple python script:

```
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fact_to_write["data"])
```

[image]

Comment: EFS is slow. That link you posted doesn't promise sub millisecond latencies, it simply says they can be "as low as" sub milliseconds. And that's for read operations. You are doing write operations which it says can be "as low as" 1.6 milliseconds.  A lot it depends on the Throughput Mode you have configured for the EFS volume, but it is never going to be as fast as a local drive.

Comment: Aside from any slowness in EFS, this question doesn't provide enough information to get a good answer. Simply showing the act of writing a file tells us nothing about how you're doing it with "100 concurrent threads" (which would make me think that the GIL is at least partly at fault). Nor do you give your Lambda specs (for all we know, you're using the minimum memory, which gives 1/16th of a CPU). And that screenshot of your log message simultaneously fails to give much information (because it's half cut off) and takes up a huge chunk of screen with repetitive data.